# Conditional constraints in MILPs

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming, binary-variable

I want to understand how to represent iff constraints in MILPs. For example, I want to represent the following as the constraints of a MILP

$$ c = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } d \geq e \\ 0 & \text{if } d < e \end{cases} $$

where $c \in \{0,1\}$ is a binary variable, $d \in [0,1]$ is a continuous variable, and $e \in [0, 1]$ is given. How should I do this? In the constraints, I want only $\geq$, $\leq$, $=$, $<$, and $>$.

I have tried consulting various resources, but they generally only talked about if-then scenarios and not this one.

Comment: (crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727412/conditional-constraints-in-milps)

Answer (score 3):

For more clarity, I have slightly changed the notations: $y_c \in \{0,1\}$ is the binary variable $c$ and $x_d \in [0,1]$ is the continuous variable $d$. I will also assume that $0<e\le 1$ to avoid ambiguity at the breakpoint $e=0$.

You want to enforce
$$
(x_d \ge e \implies y_c=1) \wedge (x_d < e \implies y_c=0)
$$
which is equivalent (via contraposition) to
$$
(y_c=0 \implies x_d < e) \wedge (y_c=1 \implies e\le x_d)
$$
You can enforce $y_c=1 \implies e\le x_d$ with:
$$
e \le x_d + (1-y_c)
$$
And $y_c=0 \implies x_d < e$ with:
$$
x_d -y_c < e 
$$
Finally, the resulting constraint is:
$$
x_d+\epsilon -y_c\le e \le x_d + (1-y_c)
$$
where $\epsilon$ is your tolerance.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your solution. But there's a slight problem:

When $x_{d} = 1$ and $e = 0$, we want $y_{c}$ to be $1$. However, the second condition ($x_{d} - y_{c} < e$) is not satisfied when $y_{c}=1$ since 

$x_{d} - y_{c} = 1 - 1 = 0$ $! < 0 = e$

Comment: Yes this breakpoint is ambiguous. I have added a comment to specify that the formulation is valid for $e>0$.

Comment: Is it not possible to generate constraints so that it works even for $e = 0$?

Comment: @AnonymousBunny No, that is not possible. For various reasons, mathematical programs require weak, not strong, inequalities. Even if it were theoretically possible, the limits of double-precision arithmetic would result in values of $x_d$ near $e$ appearing to equal (or even exceed) $e.$ So you need to choose $epsilon > 0$ large enough to prevent rounding error from causing incorrect results, and you are stuck with $(e - \epsilon, e)$ being removed from the domain of $x_d.$